# Is there any efficient and small-scale compost heat recovery(CHR) system?

Tags: electricity, food, heating, composting, natural-gas

I want to develop a system mainly based on compost heat recovery technology.

Much research has already been in the past years and some good DIY designs established for farms to warm greenhouses. But what I want is a small and modularized system like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYIbrURqwoE

It was developed by students from the University of Utah in 2017.
It is comparatively small and I want to build my system based on it.

Unfortunately, I could not find any more data of this project on *researchgate.net* and *NBCI*.

I wish to learn more about **small-scale CHR systems** which are proven to be **efficient**.